# R - Capture the group_by dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using iris dataframe

```
     Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width 
1     setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     
2     setosa          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     
3     setosa          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     
4     setosa          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     
5     setosa          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     
6     setosa          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     
7  virginica          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5   
8  virginica          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3   
9  virginica          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9   
10 virginica          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0   
11 virginica          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3   
12 virginica          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8
```

I would like to group the dataframe by Species and summarise the data using a custom generic function

My proposed code is the following:

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(MySummary= GenericSummaryFunction(.))
GenericSummaryFunction <- function (x){.....}
```

The problem I am facing is that the dataframe being passed to GenericSummaryFunction is ungrouped, thus the output is not group specific.

```
  Species   MySummary
  <fct>         <dbl>
1 setosa         5.80
2 virginica      5.80
```

I am not sure what to replace "." for in `iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise(MySummary= GenericSummaryFunction(.))`  to pass the grouped dataframe instead of the whole dataframe. I am using dyplr 0.83

Comment: What should `GenericSummaryFunction` do? Does it have to be applied to all the columns or just few of the columns?

Comment: Is `.` representing a _generic_ column, or is this what you're putting in the function?

Comment: In dplyr 1.0, replacing the `.` by `across()` does what you want. Not sure if it would work in dplyr 0.83.

Comment: @Ronak Shah: It uses all columns

Comment: @Paul: That is what I am putting in the function currently

Comment: @Bas: I am stuck with dyplr 0.83 :(

Comment: Can you show your expected output?

Comment: I think you're looking for `do` then: `do(GenericSummaryFunction(.))`

Comment: You could use the `aggregate()` function, which takes any custom function.You can just pass your function using the argument `FUN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this and tell me if you have problems.
It should work with older versions of dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

GenericSummaryFunction <- function(x){
  
  # I just came up with something meaningless to get one number
  sum(x)
  
}


iris %>%
  nest(-Species) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, GenericSummaryFunction)) %>% 
  unnest()
```